# break <aura:iteration> loop after certain indexVar

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Is there a way to break aura:iteration on certain count. I know , the best way to deal this in controller and provide the right count in items, however, i have got stuck in a situation where I was looking for breaking the `<aura:iteration>` based on indexVar. Thanks a lot .

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: You can use aura:if and stop rendering after certain index. Not super efficient, but should work.

Answer (score 9):

Can we not use `start` and `end` [attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_iteration.htm) to break the loop?

Here is the working sample:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:iteration start="3" end="6" items="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" var="item">
        {!item} <br/>
    </aura:iteration>    
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Where did you find `start` and `end` attributes, they are not listed in the [`aura:iteration`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm) documentation.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_iteration.htm

Comment: +1 Nice finding!

Comment: If the restriction is more about content than index, you can also wrap the interior of the iteration with an `aura:if` so that it will only render items meeting that criteria.